# Running tests in webstorm and getting config error: Unrecognized option "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile"

Tags: jestjs, webstorm, react-scripts

I've started a brand new react project with `create-react-app`, and I want to be able to run the tests from webstorm.

But when I run the tests, I get this error:

`Unrecognized option "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile".`.   I couldn't find where `setupTestFrameworkScriptFile` is being set.
How can I make that error disappear?

Here I attach my webstorm configuration.
[image]

Comment: do you have `"setupTestFrameworkScriptFile"` anywhere in your Jest configs? check your `package.json`, `"jest": {}`

Comment: Nope, it's just a brand-new create-react-app project.

Comment: what IDE build do you use?

Comment: @lena, I think you're on the right track now,  build #WS-172.4343.25 .  Webstorm 2017.2.5.  It seems it's too old.   I've upgraded to the latest version and seems to be working :) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Fixed after upgrading to Webstorm 2019.3.2